# Sum ALL distances between coordinates MySQL - kilometers driven

Tags: mysql, sql

In my application, while the user moves I record his geolocation.

Now, I need to build a report containing the kilometers driven of the day.

Searching I found this query, it really works, but returns a float different of my calcules (I think it isn't in kilometers).

```
SELECT SUM(SQRT(POW(A.LAT - B.LAT, 2)+POW(A.LON - B.LON, 2)))
FROM LOCATIONS A
JOIN LOCATIONS B ON (A.ID = B.ID - 1)
```

I need basically the same thing, but in kilometers.

Can anyone help me?

PS: Is my English understandable?

Edit:
The query is resulting 0.09276581556846489 it should be something like 5.35 km.

I'm using javascript to calcule the distance on client-side.

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;    // Math.PI / 180
    var c = Math.cos;
    var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) *
        (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;

    return 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km
}
```

Comment: Are you using any scripting language ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your English is understandable but your schema isn't. If your table contains points x,y and z with id 1, then you are not calculating the distance between x and z, but rather x to z plus z to x plus x to y plus y to x plus y to z plus z to y.

Answer (score 1):

A degree is roughly 111 kilometers at the equator. Since you are doing a very basic calculation just multiplying by this value would be sufficient.

But if you are working with spatial data, you should really upgrade to mysql 5.7 and use the built in [spatial functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html) that makes life a lot easier.

Comment: I can use spatial functions, what should I do?  I did a row called point and inserted POINT(latitude,longitude). Now how do I calcule the kilometers driven?

Comment: I think you should post a different question for that

Comment: As I edited the post... The query is resulting 0.09276581556846489 it should be something like 5.35 km. Multiplying by 111 still wrong :/

Comment: like I said, please post a new qustion. Show your tables. instead of these hard to understand A, B use real names